# Every set in $L(\mathbb{R})$ is $^{\omega}On\text{-definable}$

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

I was reading Solovay's celebrated theorem on the existence of a model of ZF,
in which every set of reals is Lebesgue-measurable from Kanamori's the higher 
infinite and I have a question.

Bellow is the statement that I think I have a proof for which has an assumption, which I don't know how to prove.

---

> Suppose now that $A \subseteq {}^{\omega}\omega$ with $A \in L(\mathbb{R})$. Then $A$ is ${}^{\omega}On\text{-definable}$.

---

Also we say that $A$ is $^{\omega}On\text{-definable}$ when there exists a formula $\psi$ and some $a \in {}^{\omega}On$ s.t.
$$ x \in A \longleftrightarrow \psi[a, x] $$

---

Ok now here are my thoughts:

We prove that for any $X \in L(\mathbb{R})$, $X$ is $^{\omega}\omega\text{-definable}$ in $L_{\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$ by induction, where $\alpha + 1$ is the first index in the hierarchy where $X$ appears.

The case $\alpha =0$ or the case for limit ordinals is immediate. Now suppose
$X \in L_{\alpha + 1}(\mathbb{R})$. Then there exists a formula $\varphi$ and 
$t_1, \dots, t_n \in L_{\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$ s.t.
$$x \in X \longleftrightarrow L_{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}) \models \varphi(x, t_1, \dots, t_n)$$
By the induction hypothesis there exist formulas $\tilde{\varphi}_1, \dots, \tilde{\varphi}_n$ and reals $a_1, \dots, a_n$ s.t. 
$$x \in t_i \longleftrightarrow L_{\alpha_{t_i}}(\mathbb{R}) \models \tilde{\varphi}_i[a_i, x]$$
Now using coding and replacing the respective formulas in $\varphi$, we arrive at a formula $\psi$ and a real $a$ s.t.
$$x \in X \longleftrightarrow \psi(x, a, L_{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}), L_{\alpha_{t_1}}(\mathbb{R}), \dots, L_{\alpha_{t_n}}(\mathbb{R})).$$

Here is the assumption I was talking about, is it Ok and safe to assume that for all $\beta$, $L_{\beta}(\mathbb{R})$ is $^{\omega}On\text{-definable}$?
If so, how can I prove it?
If all I have written is incorrect, then how can I prove the main statement?

---

**EDIT I:** The $^{\omega}On\text{-definability}$ of $A$ in the main statement should be checked in $V[G]$, where $G$ is any generic filter on the Levy collapse of an inaccessible cardinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your proof shows that $X$ is $^{\omega}On$-definable in $L(\mathbb R)$ (instead of in $L_\alpha(\mathbb R)$ as you claimed) - which is of course totally fine for what you want to do. The proof itself looks totally fine to me.

Now to your assumption: Yes, $L_\beta(\mathbb R)$ is $^{\omega}On$-definable. Even better: There is a definition of $L_\beta(\mathbb R)$ with only parameter $\beta$ that is uniform in $\beta$. This definition is just the usual definition of $L_\beta(\mathbb R)$:
$$X=L_\beta(\mathbb R)\text{ iff there is a function } f \text{ with domain } \beta+1 \text{ so that } f(0)=tc(\{\mathbb R\}), \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{ for all successors } \alpha+1\leq\beta\ f(\alpha+1)=Def(f(\alpha)) \text{ and for all limit } \alpha\leq\beta\\\  f(\alpha)=\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha} f(\gamma) \text{ and } X=f(\beta)$$
Where $Def(f(\alpha))$ is the definable powerset of $f(\alpha)$.

With your ideas, you can even improve your result and show that $L(\mathbb R)\models\ V=HOD_{\mathbb R}$, where $HOD_\mathbb R$ is the class of sets that are hereditarily definable from ordinals and reals as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought about this myself but when I came about using $\mathbb{R}$, well I got stuck because I thought that I have used an illegal parameter, completely ignoring the fact that $\mathbb{R}$, is definable through $\omega$! Seeing it written down helped.

Comment: Also about the last part of your answer, because in $V[G]$ we have shown that, $L(\mathbb{R}) = HOD^{L(\mathbb{R})}_{\mathbb{R}}$, using the specific formulas in the proof we can argue by the absoluteness of the satisfaction relation for sets and absoluteness of constructibility, that $L(\mathbb{R}) \models V = HOD_{\mathbb{R}}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Instead you could also assume $V=L(\mathbb R)$. Glad that I could help!